# value get selected in every dropdown when try to select one dropdown in react native

Tags: react-native, expo, dropdown, react-native-flatlist

I am new to react native. I cannot figure out how to show selected values from dropdown. I have inserted a dropdown in a data table. When I try to select value from any drop down every dropdown showing the same value. Also I an trying to store values in single useState.. I have searched a lot.. Please help me..
[Here is expo snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pintuparamanik/d56b69)
here is my code -

```
import React, {Component, useState} from 'react';
import { FlatList,StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
 
import { DataTable } from 'react-native-paper';
 import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-element-dropdown';

const optionsPerPage = [2, 3, 4];
  const data2 = [
    { label: 'Item 1', value: '1' },
    { label: 'Item 2', value: '2' },
    { label: 'Item 3', value: '3' },
    { label: 'Item 4', value: '4' },
    { label: 'Item 5', value: '5' },
    { label: 'Item 6', value: '6' },
    { label: 'Item 7', value: '7' },
    { label: 'Item 8', value: '8' },
  ];

const MyComponent = () => {
  const data = [...Array(20).keys()];
    const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
    const [isFocus, setIsFocus] = useState(false);
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
  const [itemsPerPage, setItemsPerPage] = React.useState(optionsPerPage[0]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setPage(0);
  }, [itemsPerPage]);

  const _renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <DataTable.Row>
      <DataTable.Cell>{item}</DataTable.Cell>
      <DataTable.Cell numeric>159</DataTable.Cell>
    
      <DataTable.Cell >
      <Dropdown
          style={[styles.dropdown, isFocus && { borderColor: 'blue' }]}
          placeholderStyle={styles.placeholderStyle}
          selectedTextStyle={styles.selectedTextStyle}
          inputSearchStyle={styles.inputSearchStyle}
          iconStyle={styles.iconStyle}
          data={data2}
          search
          maxHeight={300}
          labelField="label"
          valueField="value"
          placeholder={!isFocus ? 'Select item' : '...'}
          searchPlaceholder="Search..."
          value={value}
          onFocus={() => setIsFocus(true)}
          onBlur={() => setIsFocus(false)}
          onChange={item => {
            setValue(item.value);
            setIsFocus(false);
          }}
          
        />
      </DataTable.Cell>
    </DataTable.Row>
  );

  return (
    <DataTable>
      <DataTable.Header>
        <DataTable.Title>Dessert</DataTable.Title>
        <DataTable.Title numeric>Calories</DataTable.Title>
        <DataTable.Title numeric>Fat</DataTable.Title>
      </DataTable.Header>

      <FlatList data={data} renderItem={_renderItem} />
    </DataTable>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      padding: 16,
    },
    dropdown: {
      height: 50,
      width:80,
      borderColor: 'gray',
      borderWidth: 0.5,
      borderRadius: 8,
      paddingHorizontal: 8,
      marginLeft:20
    },
    icon: {
      marginRight: 5,
    },
    label: {
      position: 'absolute',
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      left: 22,
      top: 8,
      zIndex: 999,
      paddingHorizontal: 8,
      fontSize: 14,
    },
    placeholderStyle: {
      fontSize: 16,
    },
    selectedTextStyle: {
      fontSize: 16,
    },
    iconStyle: {
      width: 20,
      height: 20,
    },
    inputSearchStyle: {
      height: 40,
      fontSize: 16,
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Tip 1: Unique ID

Whenever iterators are used provide `key`. In `<FlatList/>` use `keyExtractor` prop.

```html
   <FlatList
      data={data}
      extraData={formValue}
      renderItem={_renderItem}
      keyExtractor={(k) => `${k}`}
   />
```

### Tip 2: Form Value

Every form element should store value as `key: value`.

```js
   // const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

   const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState({});
```

Getter/Setter for form values.

```js
   const _getValue = () => {
      if (item in formValue) return formValue[item];
      return null;
   };
   const _onChange = (obj) => {
      setFormValue((v) => ({ ...v, [item]: obj.value }));
      setIsFocusId(null);
   };
```

### Tip 3: Focused Value

Since there are various elements better to give each element an `ID`.

```js
   // const [isFocus, setIsFocus] = useState(false);

   const [isFocusId, setIsFocusId] = useState(null);
```

onFocus/onBlur

```js
   // onFocus={() => setIsFocus(true)}
   // onBlur={() => setIsFocus(false)}
   // onFocus={() => setIsFocusId(item)}
   // onBlur={() => setIsFocusId(null)}
```

#### Solution: https://snack.expo.dev/@fanish/95b120